# Change form of webservice response to array in java

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap

I develop an android application and i send a class object to a webservice method and i supposed to take an array as response but it returns anyType{}.

Here is a part of my code.

```
            Customer C = new Customer();
            C.setProperty(0,"30000001");

            PropertyInfo pi =new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("customer");        
            pi.setValue(C);            
            pi.setType(C.getClass());  
            request.addProperty(pi);   



            try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                String[] denemeList;

                denemeList = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

                for(int i=0; i<response.getPropertyCount(); i++)
                { 

                   denemeList[i] = response.getPropertyAsString(i).toString();
                   Log.d("This is the response",denemeList[i]);

                } 
                }catch (Exception e) {
                     TextView01.setText("EXCEPTION");
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I find some other codes except from this one but none of them work.
Anyone know what should i do?

Thanks.

Comment: are u getting any errors? if yes kindly post it here

Comment: thanks for the reply.
In LogCat (cause i run it from eclipse) it gives me a warning: "java.lag.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException : Array index out of range".

Comment: first do one thing, i think u hv issue parsing the data from server , make sure that response.toString() gives u output and code below reponse line comment it out

Comment: i put this line: "System.out.println("--response--" +response.toString());" after the response and it returns me "--response--GetCustomerResponse{GetCustomerResult=anyType{};}" but i dont know if its good or bad.

Comment: i m sorry use Object response1 = envelope.getResponse(); and print it Log.i("myApp", response1.toString()); and let me know whats the output

Comment: Again the same problem.It returns me anyType{}.

Comment: can u post me ur service on my mailid?if possible

Comment: Thats fine, i m posting one class to you try putting ur varibles there and just call getDistrictDetials() in ur class .....NOTE: this is sample class for you u need to replace the variables used in ur class

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE : HERE IS MY CLASS , I THINK IT WILL HELP YOU JUST POST tHIS
>   CLASS AS IT IS IN UR PROJECT 2. REPLACE THE VARIABLE ACCORDINGLY 3.
>   CALL METHOD : getDistrictDetials IN SUPPOSE MAIN CLASS...THIS WILL
>   PRINT THE OUTPUT IN CONSOL WINDOW

```
public class WebServiceCaller {

    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://www.MYSERVICE/Service.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/RASHTRWADI_State";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "RASHTRWADI_State";



    public boolean getDistrictDetials() {
        boolean result = false;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo propInfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo1.setName("State_Code");
        propInfo1.setValue(1);
        propInfo1.setType(int.class);
        request.addProperty(propInfo1);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true; // put this only if the web service is .NET one
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            // SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Object response1 = envelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) response1;

            Log.i("myApp", response1.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: I create a this class and i call the getDistrictDetials but in the console it returns me these:

[2013-07-24 15:25:19 - TestCustomer22] ------------------------------
[2013-07-24 15:25:19 - TestCustomer22] Android Launch!
[2013-07-24 15:25:19 - TestCustomer22] adb is running normally.
[2013-07-24 15:25:19 - TestCustomer22] Performing com.testcustomer22.MainActivity activity launch

i continue the return message in the next comment cause it was too long...

Comment: [2013-07-24 15:25:19 - TestCustomer22] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'ggghh' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2013-07-24 15:25:19 - TestCustomer22] Uploading TestCustomer22.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-07-24 15:25:23 - TestCustomer22] Installing TestCustomer22.apk...
[2013-07-24 15:25:31 - TestCustomer22] Success!
[2013-07-24 15:25:32 - TestCustomer22] Starting activity com.testcustomer22.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

Comment: [2013-07-24 15:25:34 - TestCustomer22] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.testcustomer22/.MainActivity }

Thanks for your help.I appreciate it.
And sorry for the 3 illegible comments.

Comment: I dont know a lot about web services but i know that the web service method takes a class object as parameter and must return an array.To explain more the app must have 3 editTexts where the user fill one of them with either the name of the customer or the code or the VATNo.And it must return an array with all the customers with this characteristic.(e.g. user gives "300*" in the code field and must return all the customers whose code starts with 300).

Comment: Alright is it possible to post service to me on mail?i can parse it